# Is "To proceed setting up your website, click here" a proper sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs

Is the following sentence grammatical?

> To proceed setting up your account, click here.

I'm suspicious of the word *proceed* in this context — isn't the word *continue* a much better fit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree. "Proceed" needs a preposition like "with", "against", or "to". "Continue" can be used with a preposition but does not require one.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, there  are  probably some initial steps to be taken before setting up a web site  such as "paying money" or "filling a form of personal information" e.t.c. So, setting up a web site is another new step after those steps.

If so, I would use **proceed to**.

> **proceed to**:   to do something after doing something else; to do sth next, after having done sth else first.

Also, **proceed to** and **proceed with** may slightly differ in meaning / sense

> **proceed with**: to continue to do something that has already been planned or started

In your case, using **continue** might also be possible. But you should be careful with the context. The closest senses of **continue**:

> 1) to keep existing or happening without stopping
>   2) to start again, or start doing something again, after an interruption

Comment: +1 I agree. But I think you need to explain that *proceed to* requires the infinitive form, not the -ing form of the initial sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be:

> To proceed ***with*** setting up your account, click here.